# Show that $A+(-A)=0$ where $A$ is a Dedekind cut.

Tags: real-analysis

Could you explain how to prove $A +(-A)=0$ precisely where A is a Dedekind cut?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us how you got started and where you are stuck. Do you understand the definitions? What other theorems have you proved about Dedekind cuts?

Comment: Also please provide the exact definition of "Dedekind cut" you're using. There are several such definitions around in the literature, which are easily seen to be variants of the same intuitive idea as far as the things that _fit_ the definitions are concerned. But since you're looking for a property of things that _don't_ fit your definition of "Dedekind cut", those usually ignored differences may well become important.

Comment: For the same reason, please define $+$ and $-$. Again, typically definitions of these operations are written with the assumption that the things they apply to _are_ reals; if you apply such a definition to something that _isn't_, details in the definition that are irrelevant when applying them to Dedekind cuts may suddenly gain importance.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** When $A_1$ represents some real value $x$, it contains all rationals less than $x$, and $A_2 = -A_1$ contains all rationals less than $-x$.

Then, if $A_3 = A_1+A_2$, then $A_3$ contains all the rationals that can be obtained by adding a rational from $A_1$ and a rational from $A_2$.  You must show that

- Any such sum must be negative.
- Any negative rational $u$ can be obtained as such a sum. You will need the property that the rationals are dense.

These two together show that all negative rationals, and only those rationals, are in $A_3$, which therefore represents $0$.